# unable to execute unix script using . script_name

Tags: unix

I am unable to execute following command in unix as

e.g. ->

```
export ENVFILE=$PARENT_DIR/../env/.tpms.evr
```

while i try to execute `. "${ENVFILE}"` it shows me error as `bash: 39910-: command not found`

can anybody let me know about how to fix this.

Answer (score 1):

You most probably have a line in .tpms.evr script which bash tries to execute as a command called "39910-"

Please share this .tpms.evr script or just that line containing "39910-"

Comment: You got is right. Just checked my .tpms.evr which has one uncommented line as 39910-  .This should have been commented.   Thanks a ton for your input. Really appreciate that